# Format Tab separated file to replace space with a character

Tags: awk

I want to convert empty space between tabs by charcater "|"
The file can be downloaded from here

```
wget http://download.cbioportal.org/cancerhotspots/cancerhotspots.v2.maf.gz


cat cancerhotspots.v2.maf | grep -v version | head -3


Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build  Chromosome  Start_Position  End_Position    Strand  Variant_Classification  Variant_Type    Reference_Allele    Tumor_Seq_Allele1   Tumor_Seq_Allele2   dbSNP_RS    dbSNP_Val_Status    Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Matched_Norm_Sample_Barcode Match_Norm_Seq_Allele1  Match_Norm_Seq_Allele2  Tumor_Validation_Allele1    Tumor_Validation_Allele2    Match_Norm_Validation_Allele1   Match_Norm_Validation_Allele2   Verification_Status Validation_Status   Mutation_Status Sequencing_Phase    Sequence_Source Validation_Method   Score   BAM_File    Sequencer   Tumor_Sample_UUID   Matched_Norm_Sample_UUID    HGVSc   HGVSp   HGVSp_Short Transcript_ID   Exon_Number t_depth t_ref_count t_alt_count n_depth n_ref_count n_alt_count all_effects Allele  Gene    Feature Feature_type    Consequence cDNA_position   CDS_position    Protein_position    Amino_acids Codons  Existing_variation  ALLELE_NUM  DISTANCE    STRAND_VEP  SYMBOL  SYMBOL_SOURCE   HGNC_ID BIOTYPE CANONICAL   CCDS    ENSP    SWISSPROT   TREMBL  UNIPARC RefSeq  SIFT    PolyPhen    EXON    INTRON  DOMAINS AF  AFR_AF  AMR_AF  ASN_AF  EAS_AF  EUR_AF  SAS_AF  AA_AF   EA_AF   CLIN_SIG    SOMATIC PUBMED  MOTIF_NAME  MOTIF_POS   HIGH_INF_POMOTIF_SCORE_CHANGE   IMPACT  PICK    VARIANT_CLASS   TSL HGVS_OFFSET PHENO   MINIMISED   ExAC_AF ExAC_AF_AFR ExAC_AF_AMR ExAC_AF_EAS ExAC_AF_FIN ExAC_AF_NFE ExAC_AF_OTH ExAC_AF_SAS GENE_PHENO  FILTER  flanking_bps    variant_id  variant_qual    ExAC_AF_Adj ExAC_AC_AN_Adj  ExAC_AC_AN  ExAC_AC_AN_AFR  ExAC_AC_AN_AMR  ExAC_AC_AN_EAS  ExAC_AC_AN_FIN  ExAC_AC_AN_NFE  ExAC_AC_AN_OTH  ExAC_AC_AN_SAS  ExAC_FILTER gnomAD_AF   gnomAD_AFR_AF   gnomAD_AMR_AF   gnomAD_ASJ_AF   gnomAD_EAS_AF   gnomAD_FIN_AF   gnomAD_NFE_AF   gnomAD_OTH_AF   gnomAD_SAS_AF   TUMORTYPE   PLATFORM    judgement   Amino_Acid_Change   Amino_Acid_Position Protein_Lenght  Reference_Amino_Acid    Variant_Amino_Acid  allele_freq tm  Amino_Acid_Length   Ref_Tri oncotree_organtype  oncotree_parent oncotree_detailed   Master_ID
WARS2   10352   .   GRCh37  1   119575617   119575617   +   Missense_Mutation   SNP C   C   T   novel       000236  NORMAL  C   C                                                               c.1000G>A   p.Val334Ile p.V334I ENST00000235521 6/6 0   .   .   0   .   .   WARS2,missense_variant,p.Val334Ile,ENST00000235521,NM_201263.2,NM_015836.3;WARS2,missense_variant,p.Val240Ile,ENST00000537870,;WARS2,3_prime_UTR_variant,,ENST00000369426,;WARS2,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000497402,;WARS2,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000495746,; T   ENSG00000116874 ENST00000235521 Transcript  missense_variant    1027/2800   1000/1083   334/360 V/I Gtt/Att     1       -1  WARS2   HGNC    12730   protein_coding  YES CCDS900.1   ENSP00000235521 Q9UGM6  B7Z5X7  UPI000004A002   NM_201263.2,NM_015836.3 tolerated(0.31) benign(0.015)   6/6     Gene3D:1.10.240.10,HAMAP:MF_00140_B,hmmpanther:PTHR10055,Low_complexity_(Seg):seg,Superfamily_domains:SSF52374,TIGRFAM_domain:TIGR00233                                                                 MODERATE    1   SNV                             ACC .   .                                                                                   acyc    exome   RETAIN  V334I   334     V   I   NA  WARS2 334   360 ACC headandneck saca    acyc    000236
OPN3    23596   .   GRCh37  1   241761094   241761094   +   Missense_Mutation   SNP G   G   A   rs780348058     000236  NORMAL  G   G                                                               c.899C>T    p.Ser300Leu p.S300L ENST00000366554 3/4 0   .   .   0   .   .   OPN3,missense_variant,p.Ser300Leu,ENST00000366554,NM_014322.2;OPN3,missense_variant,p.Ser221Leu,ENST00000331838,;KMO,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000366559,NM_003679.4;KMO,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000366557,;KMO,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000366555,;OPN3,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,,ENST00000469376,;OPN3,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,,ENST00000490673,;OPN3,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,,ENST00000478849,;OPN3,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,,ENST00000463155,;OPN3,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,,ENST00000462265,;    A   ENSG00000054277 ENST00000366554 Transcript  missense_variant    1006/2620   899/1209    300/402 S/L tCg/tTg rs780348058 1       -1  OPN3    HGNC    14007   protein_coding  YES CCDS31072.1 ENSP00000355512 Q9H1Y3      UPI000000165B   NM_014322.2 deleterious(0.02)   possibly_damaging(0.692)    3/4     Transmembrane_helices:TMhelix,PROSITE_profiles:PS50262,hmmpanther:PTHR24240:SF64,hmmpanther:PTHR24240,PROSITE_patterns:PS00238,Gene3D:1.20.1070.10,Pfam_domain:PF00001,Superfamily_domains:SSF81321,Prints_domain:PR00237                                                                   MODERATE    1   SNV     9.415e-06   0   0   0.0001278   0   0   0   0       .   CGA .   .   9.426e-06   1/106086    1/106208    0/9066  0/11158 1/7822  0/6612  0/54326 0/694   0/16408 PASS                                        acyc    exome   RETAIN  S300L   300     NA  OPN3 300    402 TCG headandneck saca    acyc    000236
```

IF the column has no value, there is an empty space between two tabs, which we see when the number of columns are counted

```
cat cancerhotspots.v2.maf | grep -v version | head -4 | awk '{ print NF }'
148
80
99
81
```

Desired output.
When the column has no value, replace empty space with character "|".

```
cat cancerhotspots.v2.maf | grep -v version | head -2 | sed 's/\t\t/\t|\t/g' 
    
    
Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build  Chromosome  Start_Position  End_Position    Strand  Variant_Classification  Variant_Type    Reference_Allele    Tumor_Seq_Allele1   Tumor_Seq_Allele2   dbSNP_RS    dbSNP_Val_Status    Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Matched_Norm_Sample_Barcode Match_Norm_Seq_Allele1  Match_Norm_Seq_Allele2  Tumor_Validation_Allele1    Tumor_Validation_Allele2    Match_Norm_Validation_Allele1   Match_Norm_Validation_Allele2   Verification_Status Validation_Status   Mutation_Status Sequencing_Phase    Sequence_Source Validation_Method   Score   BAM_File    Sequencer   Tumor_Sample_UUID   Matched_Norm_Sample_UUID    HGVSc   HGVSp   HGVSp_Short Transcript_ID   Exon_Number t_depth t_ref_count t_alt_count n_depth n_ref_count n_alt_count all_effects Allele  Gene    Feature Feature_type    Consequence cDNA_position   CDS_position    Protein_position    Amino_acids Codons  Existing_variation  ALLELE_NUM  DISTANCE    STRAND_VEP  SYMBOL  SYMBOL_SOURCE   HGNC_ID BIOTYPE CANONICAL   CCDS    ENSP    SWISSPROT   TREMBL  UNIPARC RefSeq  SIFT    PolyPhen    EXON    INTRON  DOMAINS AF  AFR_AF  AMR_AF  ASN_AF  EAS_AF  EUR_AF  SAS_AF  AA_AF   EA_AF   CLIN_SIG    SOMATIC PUBMED  MOTIF_NAME  MOTIF_POS   HIGH_INF_POMOTIF_SCORE_CHANGE   IMPACT  PICK    VARIANT_CLASS   TSL HGVS_OFFSET PHENO   MINIMISED   ExAC_AF ExAC_AF_AFR ExAC_AF_AMR ExAC_AF_EAS ExAC_AF_FIN ExAC_AF_NFE ExAC_AF_OTH ExAC_AF_SAS GENE_PHENO  FILTER  flanking_bps    variant_id  variant_qual    ExAC_AF_Adj ExAC_AC_AN_Adj  ExAC_AC_AN  ExAC_AC_AN_AFR  ExAC_AC_AN_AMR  ExAC_AC_AN_EAS  ExAC_AC_AN_FIN  ExAC_AC_AN_NFE  ExAC_AC_AN_OTH  ExAC_AC_AN_SAS  ExAC_FILTER gnomAD_AF   gnomAD_AFR_AF   gnomAD_AMR_AF   gnomAD_ASJ_AF   gnomAD_EAS_AF   gnomAD_FIN_AF   gnomAD_NFE_AF   gnomAD_OTH_AF   gnomAD_SAS_AF   TUMORTYPE   PLATFORM    judgement   Amino_Acid_Change   Amino_Acid_Position Protein_Lenght  Reference_Amino_Acid    Variant_Amino_Acid  allele_freq tm  Amino_Acid_Length   Ref_Tri oncotree_organtype  oncotree_parent oncotree_detailed   Master_ID
    WARS2   10352   .   GRCh37  1   119575617   119575617   +   Missense_Mutation   SNP C   C   T   novel   |   000236  NORMAL  C   C   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |   c.1000G>A   p.Val334Ile p.V334I ENST00000235521 6/6 0   .   .   0   .   .   WARS2,missense_variant,p.Val334Ile,ENST00000235521,NM_201263.2,NM_015836.3;WARS2,missense_variant,p.Val240Ile,ENST00000537870,;WARS2,3_prime_UTR_variant,,ENST00000369426,;WARS2,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000497402,;WARS2,downstream_gene_variant,,ENST00000495746,; T   ENSG00000116874 ENST00000235521 Transcript  missense_variant    1027/2800   1000/1083   334/360 V/I Gtt/Att |   1   |   -1  WARS2   HGNC    12730   protein_coding  YES CCDS900.1   ENSP00000235521 Q9UGM6  B7Z5X7  UPI000004A002   NM_201263.2,NM_015836.3 tolerated(0.31) benign(0.015)   6/6 |   Gene3D:1.10.240.10,HAMAP:MF_00140_B,hmmpanther:PTHR10055,Low_complexity_(Seg):seg,Superfamily_domains:SSF52374,TIGRFAM_domain:TIGR00233 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       MODERATE    1   SNV |       |       |       |   ACC .   .   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       acyc    exome   RETAIN  V334I   334 |   V   I   NA  WARS2 334   360 ACC headandneck saca    acyc    000236



cat cancerhotspots.v2.maf | grep -v version | head -4 | sed 's/\t\t/\t|\t/g'  | awk '{ print NF }'

148
118
128
118
```

Output should have been 148 columns but there is a difference with column-count of header which is 148.

How to make all columns are uniformly padded with "|" when there is a space.

Thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately your question is difficult to understand currently. Please rephase your question so that it contains (1) a small excerpt of what your input looks like (i.e. in the question body, not linked for download), (2) the desired output for the example input you provided, and (3) what you already tried, so that contributors don't suggest solutions that you know already to be ineffective.

Comment: `awk '{while(sub(/\t\t/, "\t|\t"))}1' `   since your regex is overlapping the 2nd tab is consumed and so isn't 
 available for the next match in a global matching. Hence we need to loop. OTW, double the tabs then do the substitute. OTW, use lookarounds `perl -pe 's/(?<=\t)(?=\t)/|/g;' `

Comment: You don't need cat, head, grep, sed, etc. when you're using awk. for example `cat cancerhotspots.v2.maf | head -5 | awk '{ print NF }'` can be written as just one awk command `awk '{print NF} NR==5{exit}' cancerhotspots.v2.maf `

Comment: It outputs the number of columns correctly. However, when some columns have empty space separated by tab, i want to replace by "|" sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you probably want is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "") $i="|"; print}' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/\t\t/\t|\t/g; s/\t\t/\t|\t/g' file
```

but it's hard to tell from the example provided.

This, using commas instead of tabs for visibility, demonstrates why you need to do the substitution twice with sed:

```
$ printf 'a,,,,b\n' | sed 's/,,/,|,/g'
a,|,,|,b

$ printf 'a,,,,b\n' | sed 's/,,/,|,/g; s/,,/,|,/g'
a,|,|,|,b
```

because the regexp `,,` matches every pair of `,`s so it matches every odd-numbered `,,` pair but the even numbered `,,` pairs are unmatched until you do the 2nd pass. Another example:

```
$ printf '12345678\n' | sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1|\2/g'
1|23|45|67|8

$ printf '12345678\n' | sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1|\2/g; s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1|\2/g'
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
```

Comment: Thank you Ed !! Your examples to explain 2nd pass was great.